# Exiting to next loop iteration on successful try

Tags: python, try-catch

Apologies if this is answered somewhere else here, but I couldn't find it.

I have a `for` loop that queries some points from the OverPass database and then assigns some values to each point depending on the return.  Because the return isn't uniform in its tags for all the points, I use a series of `try-catch` statements to assess if a tag is present, what its value is, and then what the assigned value should be.  The tags appear in dictionary form, but there is no uniform set of keys.

Example:

```
for lat, lon in zip(df['PosLat'], df['PosLon']):
...
...
    if result.ways:
        way = result.ways[0]
        try:
            if dict[key1] == value1:
                #append values to lists
                continue
            elif dict[key1] == value2:
                #append different values to lists
                continue
            else:
                pass
        except KeyError:
            pass
        try:
            if dict[key2] == value1:
                #append values to lists
                continue
            elif dict[key2] == value2:
                #append different values to lists
                continue
            elif dict[key2] == value3:
                #append still different values to lists
            else:
                pass
        except KeyError:
            pass
```

What I would like to be able to do is exit the current iteration of the for loop when a try block successfully completes, and continue the same iteration if it does not or if an exception is thrown.  As my code sits now, multiple values are being appended to `list1` and `list2` on each iteration.  I have tried `continue` and `break`, but `continue` seems to be either exiting to the if-statement or back to the try block, and `break` exits the entire for-loop.

I also tried nesting the try-catch statements but that seemed to get very messy and repetitive.

Comment: Not that your original code is particularly hard to read, but I'd beat you'd get more answers if you created a [mcve] that clearly and concisely demonstrated your problem. Right now, potential answers have to read through several lines of unrelated logic.

Comment: which iteration you want to exit ?

Comment: `KeyError` is never raised by your `append` statements.

Comment: Also, what exactly is meant by _"a try statement's condition is met"_? `try` blocks have no "condition". Do you mean you want to break from the loop if the try block completes successfully and reaches the end?

Comment: I was just about to bring that point up @Jean-FrançoisFabre. I really don't see why the OP even has `try/except` blocks there.

Comment: When the desired `try` block succeeds, use the `break` keyword to escape the loop.

Comment: @Dadep I want to skip the rest of the current iteration of the `for` loop.

Comment: @ChrisM. You should use `continue` to skip the rest of the iteration. See my answer.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The append statements are not intended to throw the error.  What will throw the error is the absence of the referenced key.  See edits for a better description of the logic.

Comment: Are ```key1``` and ```key2``` ever the same?

Comment: @wwii They are not.  They're explicit and not dynamic.

Comment: ```continue seems to be either exiting to the if-statement or back to the try block,``` - what makes you think that? Can you make a toy example that illustrates what is happening? [mcve]??

Comment: @wwii While I know `continue` is used in `for` and `while` loops (and in fact, I use it earlier in the program to avoid over-querying the server), after a single iteration of the loop I get multiple values in my lists.  I'll try to make up a toy example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't fully understand your problem, but it sounds like you may have a misunderstanding of `continue` and `break`. They are simple once you understand how they work and I hope after this explanation you will be able to be able to use them to achieve your goal.

## Continue

`continue` will simply stop the current iteration, and go to the start of the next iteration.

```
for i in range(10):
    if i == 5:
        continue
    print(i)

0
1
2
3
4
6 # It skipped 5!
7
8
9
```

## Break

`break` will exit the entire loop, so no other iterations will happen after.

```
for i in range(10):
    if i == 5:
        break
    print(i)

0
1
2
3
4
# The entire loop stopped at 5
```

Comment: @ChristianDean It doesn't actually sound like they want to use `break` at all. OP wants to skip the iteration if the key exists.

Comment: @ChristianDean I don't think `break` is what I want.  That will end the loop prematurely.  I want to continue the loop from the next iteration, which I thought is what `continue` did, but it doesn't seem to work inside of a try-catch.

Comment: @AChampion Actually, after re-reading the question, I see my comment was somewhat misinformed. I failed to see that the OP wanted to break from the current iteration, not from the entire loop. I agree, the OP seems to be confused about how to use `continue`. I guess in a way this does answer the OP's question, but I think it would be beneficially to show the OP how to correctly use `continue` in his _actual_ program.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer as an informative example of the uses of `break` and `continue`.  Turns out I was doing it correctly, but in terminating the iterations of my loops, certain things downstream weren't being updated correctly, giving a false sense of extra values being added.

Answer (score 0):

The joy of making up toy examples is that sometimes you figure out what's wrong with your source code.  Turns out I'm using `continue` right after all, and what's happening is that, by skipping the rest of the iteration, I'm not updating everything downstream correctly for the next iteration.  Hence the thought that `continue` is not exiting the loop.

So the egg is on my face.  Thanks for your help, folks.